# How to add spinner in splash screen in android phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, screen, spinner, splash-screen

I am working on a android application using Phonegap + Jquery mobile, and I have one splash screen shown when starting the app, but it's a static png file, now my customer keep asking for some loading indicator like spinner or progress bar in the splash screen while user  waiting the app being loaded.

I follow one example to show progress bar in the splash screen, but it doesn't work, below it's my code.

main java:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final Activity activity = this;
final ProgressBar progessBar1;
View footer = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.spinner, null);
root.addView(footer);

progessBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) { 
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            if(progress < 100 && progessBar1.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
            progessBar1.setProgress(progress);
            if(progress == 100) {
                progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }

            Log.d("Progress", progress+"");

         }
    });

super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Wait, loading packages ...");


super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 12000);
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 12000);
```

and the spinner.xml in the res/layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxHeight="10dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but it doesn't show the progress bar.

My questions:

1. anyone can help to point out where i did wrong, thanks.
2. any other way to do this, actually i just want to show a spinner on the splash screen, that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your splash image has transparent background.

Splashscreen hogs the whole screen space hiding the progress bar behind. I tried to bringtofront() the progress bar that also does not show it over the splash screen.

I tried running your code it throws nullpointer exception on

```
    this.appView.setWebChromeClient.....
```

because *appView* is null at this line.

I changed the code to the following((i.e load url prior to setwebchromeclient) and it shows the splash screen and progress bar together.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Activity activity = this;
    final ProgressBar progessBar1;

    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Wait, loading packages ...");
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 20000);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 20000);


    View footer = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.testspinner, null);
    root.addView(footer);

    progessBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar11);

    this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            if (progress < 100
                    && progessBar1.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
            progessBar1.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                progessBar1.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }

            Log.d("Progress", progress + "");

        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Catimos, Thanks for the reply, i still can't get it working, can share your code sample how you do it?

Comment: Your code is ok. No change is required. 

The splash.png (or splash.9.png) should have transparent background. I use paint.net for editing images.

Comment: The progress bar is running behind the splash screen. If you check logcat the progress value is displaying.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried to change background to transparent, but still can't see it, it just got black background.

Comment: I tried running your code and found issues. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Catimos, thanks a lot for your reply, i tried to run your code and i got below exceptions. FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.accoladewios.apps.jetabout.MainActivity$1.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:42),  is it because i define the progressbar wrongly?

Comment: Hi Catimos, pls refer to my answer, help to point out where i did wrong, thanks!

Comment: Hi Catimos, thanks for your code, it's working, can I ask you one more question? Now i can see my splashscreen together with the progressbar, but my issue is the progressbar is showing very shortly then disappear while my splashscreen still there, how to make them in sync? means show together, disappear also together, thanks.

Comment: The splashscreen will hide on its own when its timeout (20secs that you have set in code) is done. Or you can hide it when the index.html file is loaded. This is done in device ready event.

 Add the following in <script> tag to hide splashscreen.  


                                                                               

  
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
               navigator.splashscreen.hide();
            }

Comment: ya, the splashscreen can hide normally, my issue is the progressbar hide too early, the splashscreen is still showing, but the progressbar finish and disappear already, seems not in sync

Comment: Did you try navigator.splashscreen.hide();

Comment: Your index page is loading too fast (because its too small) for you to see the progress bar moving.
There is only this much to be done to get the splash and progress bar working together.

Comment: I recently found that the following permission is required for the splashscreen to hide.   

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   Otherwise splash screen will hide when it timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

This also won't look the way you want it, I believe. Added the same ProgressBar widget at one point and it was the same (ugly) loading bar--on my droid3, at least--that shows up on the OS browser when your looking at a webpage through the browser. This is not good for the "native" look and feel.

Comment: hi obitusis, thanks for the reply, i also feel that, do you have any better solution instead of showing a progressbar?

Comment: an html/css/javascript solution might be the simplest alternative here

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are getting nullpointer exception because the id of progressbar in your code does not match the id in your layout file.

The following line

```
com.accoladewios.apps.jetabout.MainActivity$1.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:42)
```

indicates the line no.42 for null pointer exception.

The progress bar id in your *splash.xml* is **progressBar1**. whereas
The following line in your code uses **progressbar1**

```
progessBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar1 );
```

If you debug your code the variable *progessBar1* after you run the above line will be null.

Fix this and the splash screen should show with the progress bar.